# Help me understand this proof of Implicit Function Theorem on Banach spaces

Tags: calculus, analysis, banach-spaces, implicit-function-theorem

$\newcommand{\INV}{{}^{-1}}$I'm reading an old script of a lecture long ago, and I need to understand the proof of the following version of the implicit function theorem, but calculus has admittedly always been a weak point.

> Let $V_1,V_2,W$ be Banach spaces, and $\Omega\subset V_1\times V_2$ an open subset containing $(x_0,y_0)$. We also have a continuously differentiable map $$f:\Omega \to W$$ with $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$  and s.t. the derivative on the second component $$D_2f_{(x_0,y_0)}: y \mapsto Df _{(x_0,y_0)}(0,y)\in W$$
>   is homeomorphic onto its image.
>
> Then there exists an open set $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2\subset \Omega$ around $(x_0,y_0)$ and a unique map $$g:\Omega_1\to \Omega_2$$ s.t $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x\in \Omega_1$.

**PROOF**

Now the proof is split into 3 steps.

> 1. Let $L \equiv D_2f_{(x_0,y_0)}$, and define $$G(x,y)\equiv y - (L^{-1}\circ f)(x,y).$$ Clearly $G(x,y)=y$ iff $f(x,y)=0$.

To now invoke the Banach fixed point theorem, we basically need to check that $G(x,\cdot)$ maps a closed ball to itself, for all $x$ in some open set.

Now is where my confusion begins.

> 2. We have 
>      $$ G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2) = L\INV \left( L(y_1 - y_2) - f(x,y_1) + f(x,y_2)\right).$$
>      $f$ is differentiable and $L$ is continuous, so there exist $\delta_1,\eta>0$ s.t.
>      $$
>    \tag{1} \lVert G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2) \rVert \leq\frac{1}{2}\lVert y_1 -
>     y_2\rVert
>    $$
>      for all $x\in U(x_0,\delta_1)$, $y_1,y_2\in U(y_0,\eta)$ [open balls]. There also exists a $\delta_2>0$ s.t. for all $x\in U(x_0,\delta_2)$ it is true that
>      $$
>    \tag{2}\lVert G(x,y_0)-G(x_0,y_0)\rVert\leq \frac{\eta}{2}.
>    $$
>      Let $\delta \equiv \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. If now $y\in B(y_0,\eta)$ [closed ball], then
>      \begin{align*}
>    \lVert G(x,y)- y_0 \rVert &= \lVert G(x,y)- G(x_0,y_0) \rVert \\
>    &\leq \lVert G(x,y)- G(x,y_0) \rVert + \lVert G(x,y_0)- G(x_0,y_0) \rVert \\
>    &\leq \frac{1}{2}\lVert y-y_0\rVert + \frac{\eta}{2}\\
>    &\leq \eta
>    \end{align*}
>      for all $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$, which just means $G(x,y)\in B(y_0,\eta)$, 
>      so $G(x,\cdot)$ maps the closed ball of radius $\eta$ around $y_0$ to itself.

The rest is

> 3. Apply Banach's fixed point theorem.

**Questions**

1. In equation $(1)$, I assume the right hand side is the epsilon for which we have taken the deltas, coming from continuity in $(x_0,y_0)$, right? But then this raises the question: Why the $\leq$ sign instead of $<$?
2. The same questions apply to equation $(2)$
3. Then, after equation $(2)$ we even start using *closed* balls.

All of this boils down to using $\leq$ where $<$ should(?) have been used.

Or is this some kind of consequence of the Banach-ness of the involved spaces?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Equation $(1)$ is true for all $y\in U(y_0,\eta).$ It is then not necessarily true for $y\in B(y_0,\eta),$ i.e. for $y\in\partial U(y_0,\eta).$ But in the last chain of inequalities (where we "prove" the assumptions for the FPT) we are assuming just that when going from the 2nd to 3rd line.

Even more, if we made the closed ball smaller by looking at $y\in B(y_0,\frac{\eta}{2})$, then the very last line would be $\leq \frac{3}{4}\eta$, which would most certainly not prove that $G(x,\cdot)$ maps the closed ball $B(y_0,\frac{\eta}{2})$ to itself.

Can we just choose $\delta_2$ s.t. in equation $(2)$ it says $\leq\frac{\eta}{4}$? There's no harm in doing that I suppose.

Comment: $a<b$ implies $a≤b$. A closed ball is used because of the fixed point theorem's assumptions, but you can check that nothing is wrong.

Comment: D'oh. But if, for example, $(2)$ is true for $x\in U(x_0,\delta_2)$, then it need not be true for $x\in B(x_0,\delta_2)$, right? I know that the closed ball around $y_0$ is important for the fixed point theorem, but I don't see why we use the closed ball around $x_0$ as well. Well, I guess there's a high chance it's a typo.

Comment: In addition when something is true on an open ball, you can make the radius a tiny bit smaller and use a closed ball instead. There is some flexibility in some definitions of analysis which is why you will see people write slightly different things than what you expect. In a sense, the important thing is somehow the picture, not the precise definition.

Comment: Actually, reading your proof again you are right, but by choosing $\delta/2$ instead the problem is fixed

Comment: Sorry for going at this again. Equation $(1)$ is true for all $y\in U(y_0,\eta)$. It is then not necessarily true for $y\in B(y_0,\eta)$. But in the last chain of inequalities (where we "prove" the assumptions for the FPT) we assume that it is, going from the 2nd to 3rd line. 

Even more, if we were looking at $y\in B(y_0,\frac{\eta}{2})$ (where the first equation holds), then the very last line would be $\leq \frac{3}{4}\eta$, which would most certainly not prove that $G(x,\cdot)$ maps $B(y_0,\frac{\eta}{2})$ to itself.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more careful to avoid your confusion. What I meant was to turn the open balls at the start into closed balls, because if they are true for (and now with correct symbols) $x\in U(x_0,\delta_1)$ and $y_1,y_2 \in U(y_0,\eta)$, then we could just choose $\delta'_1=\delta_1/2$, and $\eta' = \eta/2$, and begin the whole process instead with $B(x_0,\delta'_1)$ and $B(y_0,\eta')$. Now all balls are closed, and there is no fussing about with 1/2s.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now. What you did before with the tacitly overloading symbols (i.e. making the radius smaller without mentioning it while still using the same symbol) is very common, and probably one of the main sources for my confusion :D

Comment: Yes, thats definitely not good to do when someone is confused. It really is my fault, I'm sorry. Glad you understand :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72231/discussion-between-jo-be-and-calvin-khor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the chat, doubt was raised on the following part of the proof:

> 2. We have 
>      $$ G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2) = L\INV \left( L(y_1 - y_2) - f(x,y_1) + f(x,y_2)\right).$$
>      $f$ is differentiable and $L$ is continuous, so there exist $\delta_1,\eta>0$ s.t.
>      $$
>    \tag{1} \lVert G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2) \rVert \leq\frac{1}{2}\lVert y_1 -
>     y_2\rVert
>    $$
>      for all $x\in U(x_0,\delta_1)$, $y_1,y_2\in U(y_0,\eta)$ [open balls].

Here is the proof of this inequality. As $L$ is a continuous linear operator that is homeormorphic onto the image (in particular bijective) the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4nIL69PPYAhWDZlAKHb-yDJwQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBounded_inverse_theorem&usg=AOvVaw2cVqmvJern4KUpLbqWhfSs) guarantees that $L^{-1}$ is also continuous.

Now also 
\begin{align}f(x,y_2) - f(x,y_1) 
&= f(x,y_2) - f(x,y_0) + f(x,y_0) - f(x,y_1) \\
&= D_2 f(x,y_0)(0,y_2 - y_1) + o(y_2-y_0) + o(y_1-y_0)
\end{align}
By the fact that $f$ is *continuously* differentiable,  we can make $L-D_2 f(x,y_0) $ arbitrarily small in operator norm. This is where the 1/2 is. Choose $\|x-x_0\|≤\delta_1$ so that the $o(\cdot)$ errors are independent of $x$ and $\|L-D_2 f(x,y_0)\|<\frac1{100\|L^{-1}\|}$, and also choose $y_1,y_2$ to lie in a radius $\eta\ll 1$ ball around $y_0$ so that the $o(\cdot)$ errors are smaller than $\frac1{100}\|y_1-y_2\|$. Then
\begin{align} \| G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2)\|
&≤\|L^{-1}\|\|L-D_2f(x,y_0)\|\|y_1-y_2\| + o(y_2-y_0) + o(y_1-y_0) \\
&≤ \frac{1}{2} \|y_1-y_2\| \end{align}

The remainder of the proof I think is more straightforward, especially after the comments. From the proof of the inequality though, it is much simpler to completely avoid talking about small open balls, when we could have chosen small enough closed balls for the results to hold.

Comment: Is $f(x,y_2) - f(x,y_0) + f(x,y_0) - f(x,y_1) = D_2 f(x,y_0)(0,y_2 - y_1)$ $+ o(y_2-y_0) + o(y_1-y_0)$ just an application of the definition of $D_2f$?

Comment: Yeah, also I didn't use a separate line for linearity of $D_2f(x,y_0)$.

Comment: @JoBe [I was even trying to be explicit, but] to neglect the $o(\cdot)$ errors you need to actually make $\|L-D_2f(x,y_0)\|$ even smaller.

Comment: I'm left with $\lVert G(x,y_1) - G(x,y_2)\rVert \leq \frac{1}{2}\lVert y_1-y_2\rVert $ $+ c\cdot \lVert \phi(y_1,y_2) \rVert$, where $\phi$ is some residual that vanishes faster than $y_1-y_2$ as we make $\eta$ smaller and take arbitrary $y_1,y_2\in U(y_0,2\eta)$. But why can I simply choose $\eta$ small enough to neglect that term? Sure, it is not the dominant term, but it still contributes to the validity of the inequality.

Comment: @JoBe yes this is my previous comment. I wasn't careful enough, I can change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @JoBe you could have fixed it any number of ways, for instance if you kept the $\frac1{2\|L^{-1}\|}$ bound then if you choose $\xi>0$ so that
$$  \|L-D_2f(x,y_0)\| + \xi = \frac1{2\|L^{-1}\|} $$
it suffices to have $$\|o(\cdot)\| ≤ \xi \|L^{-1}\|\|y_1-y_2\|$$
I just chose to go with the realisation that the $1/2$ can be made arbitrarily smaller